# Custom User django model and openshift issues

Tags: django, openshift

[Here](http://goo.gl/gYLIr0) I described the way I extended custom User. Locally it works fine I can login to admin panel add new users etc. But once I deployed my application to openshift, after syncdb and though I created a superuser, I can't login either in the admin backend nor in the frontend. I can't seem to be able to catch the error, It says that my login and password are incorrect. But I created another superuser account and still the same. Why is that? How can I catch the error?

Comment: It solved itself after restarting application. Does it have to do that app is scalable and using a load balancer that makes changes appear slower?

Answer (score 0):

Since your "Here" link you posted isn't working (question was removed), I'm missing some context on your situation...

Scalable applications are essentially copies of your gear load-balanced by HA-Proxy. So if you change the underlying gear without restarting your app the copied scaled gears aren't going to contain the same changes. This normally isn't an issue since a "git push" will stop your application and then redeploy it with the latest set of changes.

Comment: You are right, It was suggested that I delete it cause of duplicate question. I know it redeploys it, and that is that makes me wonder why didn't it update. Anyways I still have issues to solve when extending CustomUser, will post another question.